# Android Studio - Create Sub Module

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-library

I created Module on Android Studio. I also want to create different Module(Library) libraries containing this Module(Library).

For example on iOS I did this with Pod Spec as follows.

```
  spec.subspec 'FlowerSDK' do |fs|
     fs.source_files = '**/SDK/Sources/FlowerSDK/**/*.{m,swift}'
     fs.dependency 'FlowerSDK'
     fs.dependency 'CoreSDK'
   end
  
   spec.subspec 'OceanSDK' do |os|
     os.source_files = '**/SDK/Sources/OceanSDK/**/*.{m,swift}'
     os.dependency 'OceanSDK'
     os.dependency 'CoreSDK'
   end
```

How can I do this on Android? The solution I can think of is; Creating 3 Modules named "CoreSDK", "OceanSDK", "FlowerSDK". Then the "OceanSDK" and "FlowerSDK" modules use the "CoreSDK" module.
Anyone have a better and better solution, idea?

Answer (score 1):

In Module level `build.gradle`, add this

`implementation project(path: ':yourModule')`

For example,

in your OceanSDK Module-->> build.gradle

`implementation project(path: ':CoreSDK')`